# Symfony2 - Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::getManager()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to call the Doctrine manager to persist an object in the database and I am getting the following error:

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry::getManager()
```

Code:

```
    $FooObj= new FooObj();
    $FooObj->setLanguage("ENG");  

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($FooObj);
    $em->flush();
```

What would be the reason for this error?

Comment: use  $em = $this->get("doctrine.orm.entity_manager") if youre in controller if youre in service inject @doctrine.orm.entity_manager

Comment: @johnSmith, Perfect!! Exactly what I was looking for. Please make it an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Just wondering did they change the code for `$this->getDoctrine()->getManger()` then? This was working for me just a week ago.

Comment: @Populus, funny thing, it was working for me yesterday and I did something today, so I assumed that I caused it. But this is making me think that it's probably an update...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if youre in controller use

```
$em = $this->get("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
```

if youre in service inject

```
@doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```